# Edit js resource with google extention

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to make an extention which would be able to access websites loaded external resources? If so, how do you detect or look for the value in that particular js file? Any information would be appreciated!

Comment: What "value" are you trying to "detect or look for"? I'm not sure what you're trying to do here…

Comment: Well I found that I can debugg with extention, but is it possible to attach the js file to the extention which then listens if the button is pressed inside the website and once is pressed, get with extension the js pressed value? Makes any sense?

Comment: see the docs for content scripts